How to Building Strings Unicode from C for mysql
I'm working with mysql in c, and I want to build a select statement with condition that uses unicode text :
char sql[2000]="SELECT * FROM  accounts WHERE accounts.loaihinh='Đã xác thực'";

Maybe it is not valid when run.  Please suggest a way to resolve this issue or suggest another solution.

What do you mean by "maybe"? What is the observed behavior? How does this differ from the expected behavior?
